# Gitblit federation with duplicate branches

Tags: git, gitblit

I have a gitblit for my projects, and another backup server with federation setup each 5 minutes.
Now I setup a distinct server and another federation server with the same kind of setup.

All works the same, except for one strange difference:
On my newly installed pair of servers, a repository with branch "master" and branch "branch1" will be federated in a repository with four branches "master", "branch1", "origin/master", and "origin/branch1".
While in my usual server, the federation retains exactly the same branches.

I do not see any difference in setup. Moreover, since it is not *that* surprising to see "origin/something", I do not even know if the possible mistake is to be found in the usual server or the new one.

Any idea why the difference?

In both cases, I have a very basic setup:

```
federation.mygit.url = ...
federation.mygit.token = ...
federation.mygit.frequency = 5 mins
federation.mygit.folder =
federation.mygit.bare = true 
federation.mygit.mirror = true 
federation.mygit.mergeAccounts = true
```